# PHP/Javascript: Uploading more files than the max_file_uploads limit

Tags: javascript, php, file, file-upload, upload

I have the following problem. I'm making a webpage from which a user can upload multiple pictures at a time. On averge this will be arround 300 pictures. The problem is that the max_file_uploads is limited to 20. I have tried it with a .htaccess file, but this didn't work either. I have mailed the webhosting company for detailes, and it appears that the website is on a shared hostserver and that the setting can't be changed. It is too expensive for the project to change to a private server.

My form looks like this:

```
 <form action="FotosGeupload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="beheer">
    <tr>
        <td width='100' height='30'>Album:</td>
        <td><select name='map'>
        <option value='1'> 1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foto's:</td>
        <td><input required type='file' name='files[]' accept="image/*" multiple></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" onclick="Loading()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My php script for uploading:

```
$dir = '../Fotoalbums/'.$_POST['mapnaam'].'/';
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key])){
        $file = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key], $dir.$file))
            {
                echo '<p>Het bestand: '.$file.' is succesvol geupload.</p>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<p>Er is iets fout gegaan tijdens het uploaden van het bestand: '.$file.'</p>';
            }
    }
}
```

I think I will need some javascript for this, so I can send multiple POST-action with 20 files each. I have no idea how to do this, every idea is welcome!

Comment: Having said that SO is not a site where someone says "hey, do me this" and others do the work for him, here are some infos: You're looking for AJAX ( Asynchronous JavaScript And XML). Google this. Also give a look to jQuery which can help you to develop your system.

Comment: @KevinCittadini , I have looked into Ajax and jQuery, but I need a function that the user can select the map to which the files need to be uploaded. Al the solutions that I found were for a hardcoded directory. I'm not asking for anyone to make it for me, I was just asking for ideas